# Leitura e visualização de imagens PolSAR (Grande quantidade de dados)

Tags: r, imagem, processamento-de-imagens

Gostaria de saber se vocês conhecem algum método para leitura e visualização de imagens que possuam uma grande quantidade de dados e que não seja possível carregar tudo na memória-RAM (+- 20 GB), pude ver e pensar em duas formas para leitura e para posterior visualização dessas imagens, segue abaixo:

**1º)** Quebrar a imagem em diversos blocos com determinadas dimensões para que seja possível visualizar e realizar outras atividades de processamento e analise dessas imagens.

**2º)** Realizar uma sub-amostragem para que seja possível visualizar a imagem com uma certa perda de qualidade eliminando determinadas linhas e colunas e visualizando a imagem final.

Vocês conhecem algum outro método? qual seria? Desde já, grato.